# Using jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

When using the AJAX functionality in jQuery, do I also have to have ASP.NET AJAX/.NET 3.5 installed also? or can I only use ASP.NET AJAX?

I'm unclear on whether or not I'm able to use AJAX in ASP.NET without ASP.NET AJAX or not.

Comment: not sure but i think it depends on what you want to do actually.
i myself created a webservice asmx file which does a few things in my project, and i can call it with the jquery Ajax function.

but i have no idea if that is best practice, if there is a better / even more secure way to handle stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, you don't need ASP.NET AJAX installed to use the AJAX functionality of jQuery.

You can call PageMethods and Web Services without needing a `ScriptManager` control (which generates the JavaScript proxy objects that allow you to use familiar syntax to call web services and page methods).

Article on [using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Article on [using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Comment: Are these the only ways to use jQuery AJAX calls to ASPX pages? Is there a way to plug into ASP.NET's lifecycle via jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first clarify the use of jQuery. jQuery is simply a javascript library, and it has nothing to to with ASP.NET or any other server side platform such as PHP or JSP.

So you can simply use jQuery side by side with ASP.NET, or even combine jQuery with ASP.NET 3.5 that has AJAX built in.

You can also use jQuery's AJAX if you like, and it still can run in ASP.NET. If you want to combine both, please test your aspx page first if you also want to use ASP.NET's UpdatePanel with jQuery's AJAX, since it can bring incompatibilities between them.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you're using jQuery you don't need ASP.NET AJAX installed.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Ajax is not needed in order to use jQuery, but the two work well together, hence the [support from Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx).